# ViewBag vs Model, in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This is more of a generic architectural question:

I'm trying to decide if it's ok for my programmers to use "ViewBags" to pass data to views that already accept Models.

My personal preference is to avoid ViewBags and build Robust Models containing all the data the view requires:

**Approach 1:**

```
MODEL A: 
- List of Employees
- Nullable integer, indicating which item from the list is currently selected
- string firstName (empty if index is null)
- string lastname (empty if index is null)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
MODEL A: 
- List of Employees

ViewBag:
- ViewBag.Index (indicating which item from the list is currently selected)
- ViewBag.FirstName
- ViewBag.LastName
```

Can anyone think of an argument why Approach2 would be better than approach 1?

thanks for your input

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion, you should ***never* use** `ViewBag` **without a very, very good reason**. [Brad Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716953/viewbag-vs-model-in-mvc-net/21717196#21717196) points out a rare example of one of those good reasons.

Say you have a master [layout](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts) (or a [partial view](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/how-do-i-work-with-data-in-aspnet-mvc-partial-views)) shared by an entire website and dozens of strongly-typed Views that each have their own Model. How do you pass data to the layout? Some strategies I've seen:

1. **Add the layout properties to every model.**

If you don't have many models or it's just one or two extra properties this could work. This can quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

2. **Have all your models inherit from a class that holds the layout data.**

I avoid creating a `ModelBase` class, but it can be necessary sometimes.

3. **Create a model for the layout and a generic model base class.**

I've seen MVC apps with several layouts that any view could utilize. If your models inherit from a base class, you may need to have a base class for each layout. To avoid duplication of effort, I would create a layout model for each of the layouts. Then something like this might work for you:

```cs
abstract class ModelBase<TLayout> {
    public TLayout Layout { get; set; }
}

class Model : ModelBase<LayoutModel2> { /* model stuff here */ }
```

4. **Put layout properties in** `ViewBag`**.**

There are rare situations I can imagine where putting the layout info in the model isn't the right call. It seems pretty commonplace for people to use their domain models as their model, and you may not want to mix layout/view data with the business/domain data, for example.

---

If you decide to use `ViewBag`, avoid this:

```cs
ViewBag.Title = "My page"
ViewBag.UserID = 123
ViewBag.UserName = "admin"
ViewBag.UserDisplayName = "Administrator"
```

There are obvious potential problems, like using different capitalization in different places (e.g. `UserId` instead of `UserID`). Less obvious is that someone could accidentally set `ViewBag.UserID` to a `string` or `Nullable<int>`:

```cs
class SomeOtherClass {
    public string UserID { get; set; } // someone uses a string...
}

ViewBag.UserID = someOtherClassObj.UserID; // now you're in trouble.
```

So if you must use `ViewBag`, I'd recommend something like this:

```cs
ViewBag.LayoutModel = new LayoutModel { UserID = User.ID, UserName = User.Name };
```

Comment: I also found that immediately casting it back to its original type on the top of the corresponding .cshtml file also eases the problem of ViewBag a little bit.

Comment: Is "Because I'm lazy" a very, very good reason?

Answer (score 6):

Personally i will choose Model as parameter, because model is strongly-type, so when it pass to view, we also can control our parameter is valid or not in field keyword.
And model is the best way for future code maintenance.

Reference for this :

[Avoid Viewbag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579673/effectively-avoiding-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 4):

When passing information to the Layout of your View

Answer (score 2):

Can you use it? Sure. Should you use it? Depends on what else you are trying to do. Usually you see the ViewBag reserved for sending data like the title of the page or something to that effect. You probably want to keep parameters that are filled from your database in your model. Mostly because of model binding as well as if you ever wanted to perform model validation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what is the scenario, if the fields one wants to pass will be just used in this specific view and they may not be made as part of an entity or a model then I would go with viewbags otherwise i would make it a model.

Comment: please clarify your answer with specifics and concrete reasoning why you are choosing what and not just opinions.