# Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, operator-keyword, viewbag

I am using MVC 5 ViewBag and trying to do

```
@if (!ViewBag.UserLoggedIn) {
   <a onclick="javascript:UserSessionManager.UserLogout()">LogOut</a>
}
```

but getting an error:

```
Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type '<null>'
```

Comment: In those cases i'd recommend to use strong type model instead of `ViewData` or `ViewBag`. Alternatively `@if (ViewBag.UserLoggedIn == null) { ... }`

Comment: See also: "[ViewBag vs Model, in MVC.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21716953/107625)".

Comment: Page refresh might change viewbag data cleared ... you should use session ... just an advice

Comment: If the user is *not* logged in, show a link to log *out*?

Comment: By the way, in an "onclick", you don't need a "javascript:" prefix - onclick is *always* javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an if-statement you can only have `true` or `false` (`boolean`'s basically) but the property `UserLoggedIn` wont exist on the `ViewBag` if it's not set and will therefor be null. So `ViewBag.UserLoggedIn` can be `null` or a `string`. You have to cast the string (which can also be `null`) to a boolean in order to use it in the if-statement. Something like this will work:

```
@{
    bool isUserLoggedIn = ViewBag.UserLoggedIn ?? false;
}

@if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
   <a onclick="javascript:UserSessionManager.UserLogout()">LogOut</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only  use `!` operator if it is comparable.So make sure that you pass **boolean** variable.If you dont want to do it,then you may want to do `UserLogout()` where `UserLoggedIn == null`.